# I'm trying to figure out what the name of this flower is

Tags: botany, species-identification

This is a flower that grows in my backyard. I really want to know the name so I can read about it and possibly get more.

[image]

Comment: Rose. (*Rosa* sp.)

Comment: can you give a location and time of year?

Comment: It has actually just started blooming again recently and I live In Ga. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 2):

That is a rose. At least we have such flowers around my flat and we called them roses for 18 years. See: [Rosa Gallica](https://www.gardenia.net/plant/Rosa-Gallica-var-Officinalis-Old-Red-Damask-Rose)

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! Please add an image and give some description of the species and provide references to support that the ID is actually correct.